# Why xcopy in Visual Studio post build event cuts some file size?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmd, xcopy

I have small issue about xcopy within Post-build event command line in Visual Studio 2017.
What I do is copying few .dll files from one build path to another directory.
This is command what I use:

```
xcopy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)Installer\Resources\" /Y /S <NUL:
```

Everything works fine until main project .dll copy begins.
It seems that xcopy after build cuts 3KBs of data and .dll file is corrupted.
I tried using the same command via CMD and it works fine, nothing is cut off.

What could be the issue in here?

[image]

Comment: Is there any other post-build command for that target?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: It seems that Visual Studio before build end makes a backup with .dll.bak1 where before that backup there is a .dll with slightly smaller .dll which xcopy is copying. 
What is that .dll.bak1 and why xcopy is not waiting until it is done?

Comment: I found that Visual Studio when building .dll, first builds .dll without references thats why .dll size is a little smaller. And this .dll is being copied by xcopy. After that Visual Studio is making a backup for that smaller .dll without references to *.dll.bak1 AND then once again VS is building a .dll with references that is bigger.
I found a solution for this. I wrote *.bat file with all xcopy commands and in post-build event I call this *.bat. Now it is working properly.